# Who Invented the Badge Names?

Tags: discussion, badges

Badges are a really nice idea and earning one is an happy event.

What I like more about badges is their names.
They are really funny and appropriate to their goal.

I was wondering how they were born and who chose their names?

Comment: Badges are "invented" by Max Badges, one of the lesser known SE employees. That is, unsurprisingly, also where they get their name from. Max treats each badge as if it were one of his children, and naming them is a personal process that hardly anyone of us seems to grasp. But as long as it makes sense to Max, I guess all is fine. P.s. One rumour is that Max also decides how many badges each user can at most earn. But this horrible pun-based rumour is not true.

Comment: @Bart: I am reminded of the reviews for [Tuscan Milk](http://www.amazon.com/Tuscan-Whole-Milk-Gallon-128/dp/B00032G1S0).

Comment: @Bart I want to accept your answer!! :D

Comment: @giammin I can't take any credit. I would prefer it if Max were to answer himself, getting the recognition he deserves.

Comment: @Bart right! Please Max if you're there, knock once

Comment: @Bart: Isn't he loosely related to Max Headroom and Max Power?

Comment: Max (most) folks, want to hear from Max :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first badges (and their names) were most likely dreamt up in the early days of the site internally. I imagine a brain storming session was held or something of that nature.

After the initial badges, more were (and continue to be) added. The names and definitions were discussed here on Meta and the community weighed in with their (our) opinions... This is the purpose of [badge-request](/questions/tagged/badge-request). Combine that tag with the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag, and you'll be able to see all of the [suggestions that were implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/badge-request+status-completed).

Comment: Bart's comment is better.  You're basically saying "someone did."

Comment: @rob - agreed... Just wanted to mention the badge request tag...

Comment: ahhh thank you that makes more sense!

Comment: @tgk - but not [as funny](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171334/who-invented-the-badge-names#comment507107_171334) :P